# Laravel API: NotFoundHttpException after upload

Tags: php, laravel, api, routes

I finallized my Laravel based REST API.
After uploading the API to the shared web hosting, I get every time
NotFoundHttpException error from the RouteCollection.

The public folder is working and displayed fine. But soon as I try to
use the API with postman I get following Errors:

```
{
"message": "",
"exception": "Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\Exception\\NotFoundHttpException",
"file": "/var/www/vhosts/cloud1.openhandwerk.de/httpdocs/API_oH/Connector/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/RouteCollection.php",
"line": 179,
"trace": [
```

Now when I visit the page by browser I only get a 404 error.

My api.php file

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

Route::prefix("v1")->group(function() {
  Route::post('login', 'Api\v1\UserController@login');
  Route::post('register', 'Api\v1\UserController@register');

  Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth:api'], function(){
    // Customers
    Route::get("customers", 'Api\v1\CustomerController@index');
    // Route::get("customer/{id}", "API/v1/CustomerController@show");
    // Route::post("customer", "API/v1/CustomerController@store");
    // Route::put("customers", "API/v1/CustomerController@store");
    // Route::delete("customers", "API/v1/CustomerController@destroy");
  });
});
```

Comment: how are you calling the route??

Comment: @zahidhasanemon what do you mean? its frome the namespace.. btw its working locally, just when I upload it to shared hosting it gets errors

Comment: i mean how are you accessing the url?? `/api/v1/customers` ??

Comment: @zahidhasanemon hey sorry i found out that the error is up to the URL like you presumed. On my local machine I have a virtualHost as a domain setup. So I access the API by api.test/v1/customers... But on the server its in sub directories

Comment: So how can I use the api on the linux server if the api is like this domain.com/folder/api/

Comment: `domain.com/folder/api/v1/customers` should work.

Comment: thanks! works everything fine now

Answer (score 1):

I think you are missing prefix `api`.
Please use `route:list` command to get list all of your routing with path.

```
php artisan route:list
```

Comment: Do you check validate input in your controller, if you have, when validate fails, Laravel will redirect to back page and will throw 404 if not found this page.